# Selecting unique id,s count greater than a specified value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Python Pandas Dataframe with the data sample given below.

- The data has multiple unique ids as shown in column 2. I am trying to keep the data of unique / distinct ids which are greater than 20 in count. The new dataframe should have the data of unique_id which are greater than 20 in count and ignore the rest.
- For instance, if the `unqiue_id '105714'` appear 20 times in the data then keep the data of relevant columns otherwise ignore it.

I tried:

```
df['unique_id'].value_counts().reset_index(name="count").query("count > 20")["unique_id"]
```

but it did not work.

### `sample_data.csv`

```py
datetime,           unique_id,   Usage
2018-01-28 00:00:00, 105714,    409.365
2018-01-28 00:05:00, 105714,    409.18
2018-01-28 00:10:00, 105714,    2424.2399
2018-01-28 00:15:00, 105714,    225.4576
2018-01-28 00:20:00, 206714,    225.2768
2018-01-28 00:25:00, 105714,    2382.1309
2018-01-28 00:30:00, 305714,    410.685
2018-01-28 00:35:00, 108714,    317.1043
```

Comment: So, you want to drop all rows which have a unique_id that occurs less than 20 times?

Comment: Have you tried using `groupby` with `count` and query any other columns with values larger than 20 `df.groupby(['unique_id']).count().query("Usage > 20").index.values`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want, here's a simple step-by-step approach

```
id_counts = df['unique_id'].value_counts()
ids_to_keep = id_counts[id_counts >= 20].index
df = df.loc[df['unique_id'].isin(ids_to_keep)]
```

Comment: Similar with callable : `ids_to_keep = df['unique_id'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x>=20].index`

Comment: @anky that's nice!  Didn't know you can pass a function to `.loc`.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case you can use `groupby(['unique_id'])` in order to group all rows by `unique_id` and count the occurrence of each group using `count()` function. This will return a DataFrame that you can use to query the result and get the `unique_id` that satisfy the condition by getting the queried data frame indices

```
df.groupby(['unique_id']).count().query("Usage > 20").index.values
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method using boolean indexing:

```
df = df[df.groupby("unique_id")["unique_id"].transform("size") > 20]
print(df)
```

Comment: When I enter `288` instead of `20`, the above solution doesn't work.